# How can I use faunaDB on the flutter?

Tags: flutter, faunadb

As FaunaDB [documentation](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/), it seems that there is no dart API nor REST API. Also, I can't find the FaunaDB package in the  [Flutter Packages](https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=faunadb).

Is there any way to use the FaunaDB on the flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently we don't offer first party support for flutter. You can build a third-party driver for Dart based on our current open source drivers if you'd like. They do use json/http under the hood. If you are targeting android another option might be to fork the java driver and switch out http clients to be android friendly and use a platform channel.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your kind information. I'll try to take have a look at an open-source driver code.

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest way to use Flutter with [FaunaDB](https://fauna.com/) is to use [FaunaDB's GraphQL interface](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/start/graphql) and Dart package [graphql_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter).

I recently managed to read data from FaunaDB using graphql_flutter, and will update this post when I have tested it more.

Comment: It sounds a nice idea. I'm looking forward to hiring your test result!

Answer (score 4):

Dart is able to use javascript libraries
[How to use JavaScript libraries in your Dart applications](https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-your-dart-applications-e44668b8595d)

You can simply use the javascript driver
https://github.com/fauna/faunadb-js

https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-simple-application-with-flutter-and-graphql-5786764df102

Comment: It sounds a nice idea!
The "js" package mentioned in [How to use JavaScript libraries in your Dart applications](https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-your-dart-applications-e44668b8595d) seems only for Web Apps, [not for Flutter](https://dev.to/graphicbeacon/comment/5ke0). So, I need to find another appropriate package, but it seems might be work well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Recently there was a new package published that can help you to use faunaDB with dart/flutter: [faunadb_http](https://pub.dev/packages/faunadb_http) This library also provides query classes that closely mimic FQL functions.